# 2D list in python writing in every row instead of just once

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble with a 2D list in Python. I want to write a word in the middle of the board. Instead, I get the word written in the middle of every row. Could someone explain to me why it's doing that and offer me a solution?

```
row = []
board = []
n = 21
longest =  "WORD"
for x in range(0, n):
    row.append('')
for x in range(0, n):
    board.append(row)
midway = len(board)/2
for x in range(0, len(board)):
    if x == midway:
        for y in range(0, len(board)):
            if y >= midway and y < midway + len(longest):
                board[midway][y] = longest[y - midway]
print board
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you constructed `board` using `row` repetitively causes the changes to appear on each line. Take a slightly different approach to build the board, and your code should work as intended.

```
board = []
n = 21
longest =  "WORD"
for x in range(0, n):
    board.append([''] * n)
midway = len(board)/2
for y in range(0, len(board)):
    if y >= midway and y < midway + len(longest):
       board[midway][y] = longest[y - midway]
print board
```

(Your outer loop was unnecessary, so it was also removed.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with you defining `row` in line 1 and then appending that same `row` to `board` 3 times. So you don't have 3 different `row`s. You have 3 references to the SAME `row`. I think that's what it's doing and I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you append the same row to construct a board, this chunk of code:

```
for x in range(0, n):
    row.append('')
for x in range(0, n):
    board.append(row)
```

You really want to append new row, but instead you add reference to the same row all the time. What this means is you store n references that point to the same location in memory, hence you make change on one, it will affect the others.

You can quickly create a board like this, this code also run faster

```
board = [['']*n for _ in range(n)]
```